# C++/Qt react to network state changed

Tags: c++, qt, networking

**The story:** I'm working on a **C++/Qt-Application** with a Websocket connection to a server. In some use cases, the network connection may not be available always (f. e. bad network coverage, someone pulls out the network cable...). So the application sould reconnect to the server as soon as the connection is available again.

**The problem:** I found some threads about this topic, using different ways. Things I tried:

- `QNetworkConfigurationManager` with the `onlineStateChanged` signal
- `QNetworkSession` with the `stateChanged` signal

But my slot onNetworkStateChange never gets called. However, Linux itself recognises if I pull the network cable:

*default console*

```
[ 2573.338735] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Down
[ 2584.358925] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
```

**The source code:**

*websocketclient.h*

```
class WebSocketClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WebSocketClient(const QUrl &url, QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    //way 1: QNetworkConfigurationManager
    void onNetworkStateChanged1(bool isOnline);
    //way 2: QNetworkSession
    void onNetworkStateChanged2(QNetworkSession::State state);
};
```

*websocketclient.cpp*

```
#include "websocketclient.h"

WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(const QUrl &url, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    url(url)
{
    //way 1
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    connect(&ncm, SIGNAL(onlineStateChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(onNetworkStateChanged1(bool)));

    //way 2
    QNetworkConfiguration ncfg = ncm.defaultConfiguration() //i also tried the configurationFromIdentifier("eth0")
    QNetworkSession session(ncfg);
    connect(&session, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QNetworkSession::State)), this, SLOT(onNetworkStateChanged(QNetworkSession::State)));

    //some websocket stuff
}

void WebSocketClient::onNetworkStateChanged1(bool isOnline)
{
    qDebug() << "Network state changed, now" << isOnline;
}

void WebSocketClient::onNetworkStateChanged2(QNetworkSession::State state)
{
    qDebug() << "Network state changed, now" << state;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `ncm` and `ncfg` go out of scope once constructor execution is done, maybe you should implement `ncm` and `ncfg` as `WebSocketClient` members?

Comment: You solved it, thanks!

Comment: It's not emit signals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ncm` and `ncfg` go out of scope once constructor execution is done, implement `ncm` and `ncfg` as `WebSocketClient` members.